# PostgreSQL table lock is freezing up

Tags: postgresql

We have a PostgreSQL function that has been running for quite some time just fine, but recently it's started hanging up for unknown reasons...

I dug into the function and the first line of the function is "lock ;"

With that line commented out, the function runs perfectly well, but allowing that table lock to run causes my function, and consequently my application to lock up (freeze) indefinitely...

The code itself is a little silly (it's legacy code that we're just maintaining at this point)... so please don't ask why this code is run... Just know that it grabs a unique ID to use for a given set of functions in the application. I also know that when it runs out of unique IDs there is a problem... We periodically flush out these IDs so there are always available IDs.

```
declare
    tmp int4;
begin
    lock table1; --the offending line
    for g in 1 .. 999 loop
        select g_id into tmp from table1 where g_id = g;
        if not found then
            insert into table1 (g_id, type, date, status) values (g, 'type', current_timestamp, 'w');
            return g;
        end if;
    end loop;
    raise exception 'unable to find unique id';
    return 0;
end;
```

Again, without the "lock" command, the function runs, but once I allow that lock command to run it hangs up. Has anyone seen similar issues with PostgreSQL and have a solution?

Comment: If `lock table1` hangs it's because #1 another transaction has a lock on `table1` and #2 it does not terminate promptly. #1 is to expect, but #2 is a problem. See https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Comment: This is a **horrible** way of generating unique IDs

Comment: I absolutely know it's awful code, haha... that's why I commented about it.  We're thankfully scrapping all the legacy code and writing an entirely new application.  That old code is a messy beast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the function hangs, look at the pg_locks table to see what's
holding the lock.  From there, you should be able to figure out
where your deadlock is.  Keep in mind that locks are held until
the end of the transaction.

Since you're doing an insert, you need the lock to avoid a race
condition on grabbing a free id and inserting it into the table.
If the application can handle it, consider using a sequence to
generate the ids instead.

As "a_horse_with_no_name" noted, this is a terrible way to look
for a new id.  SQL is set based, so use set operations to find
unused ids.

By way of example:

First, a test data table.  You won't need this, since you'd
use your own table1.

```
create temp table table1 (g_id integer);
insert into table1
select x from generate_series(1,999) x
where random() < 0.10;
```

Get an unused id:

```
select
generate_series(1,999) new_id
except
select g_id from table1
limit 1;
```

If you need the lowest unused id, then use:

```
with unused as (
select
generate_series(1,999) new_id
except
select g_id from table1
)
select new_id from unused order by new_id limit 1;
```

Comment: thanks for the example, I know it's bad code... this is legacy code that was here long before I arrived... we're not really focused on updating old code because we're re-coding the entire application to be web-based

Comment: guess I'll see what I can find from the pg_locks table as that seems to be the way to go